# How to pass string value from view to controller js in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

How to pass string value from test.html.ftl (view ) to test.get.js (contoller javascript ) in alfresco.

thanks

janaka

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible, take a look at the [MVC pattern](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/3.0_Web_Scripts_Framework#Web_Script_MVC) of webscripts from the Alfresco Wiki.

In the picture at nr 4, the controller(JavaScript) sends variables through the model to the view(Freemarker). Sot it's not possible to send parameters from the view to the controller.

What is possible is to send parameters from the view to another webscript controller. E.g. create a submit form and submit it to a post webscript (post.js) or use client-side JavaScript to post/get it to the other webscript.

[image]